# Remove commits between commits

Tags: git

I have 3 branches:

- master
- test1
- test2

`master` state is:

```
          HEAD
           |
           |
 A -- B -- C
```

`test1` state:

```
                    HEAD
                     |
                     |
 A -- B -- C -- D -- E
```

And `test2` state:

```
                              HEAD
                               |
                               |
 A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G
```

Now i need to rebase `test2` branch that base for it will be master, as:

```
                    HEAD
                     |
                     |
 A -- B -- C -- F -- G
```

How to do it correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git rebase --onto master test1 test2`

Comment: Thank you @abyss, it helps. Will accept your answer as soon as i can. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can see all commit by `git log`... then you can checkout specific commit and can play around with that. see this [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-previous-git-commit) I hope you will find you answer here.